# SciFi series from the 80s (or 70s?): main character with bionic powers

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I recall it being a series of books, each being approximately 200 pages or so.

The main character I recall had 'bionic' powers - or, his skeleton was made out of some indestructible type of metal or something...

If I'm recalling it correctly he had a sidekick named 'wolf' perhaps?

Sorry, that's about all I can remember.  Would LOVE to find this series again!

Edit: After googling 'science fiction metal skeleton' I turn up the 'Last Legionary' series by Douglas Hill.  The name of the series rings a bell, the name of the main character rings a bell (Keill Randor), BUT...  His sidekick is described as a telepathic 'bat' named Glr.  I don't remember this...  I could swear that the sidekick was some type of hairy creature named 'wolf' or 'bear' or 'baer'.... ?

Comment: Was there a scene, late in the book, where his skeleton had recently been replaced with the unbreakable material, and he took advantage of it to win a fight?  Specifically, going up against a very 'by the book' martial artist, he leaves an opening, where the standard response would result in his arm being broken, but, since he knows it CAN'T break, he uses it to his advantage to win the fight?  If so, I've been trying to remember it for years.. I THOUGHT it was Andre Norton, but haven't been able to find it yet.

Comment: Wow, yes, that sounds very familiar!

Comment: Okay... After uncovering the 'library bound' covers of this series and seeing the cover artwork I'm now pretty confident it's the Last Legionary books.  I'll order Galactic Warlord and see if I can find this wolf/baer fellow.  :)

Comment: I think you may be right; this [cover](http://www.amazon.com/GALACTIC-WARLORD/dp/B0014XUY0I/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1358271346&sr=8-2&keywords=Galactic+Warlord) looks very familiar to me, too.

Comment: I know of a character with a metallized skeleton, but no sidekick. It's the character himself who has "Wolf" in his name...

Answer (score 4):

This absolutely is the Last Legionaire series, specifically the Galactic Warlord.  In the fight mentioned above Keill Randor uses the "indestructible non-breaking arm" technique after being unable to penetrate the organic body armor of his opponent Thr'un.

As I recall the passage went something like, "In the Martial Games of Moros, such a blow from the fist of Keill Randor had smashed through slabs of concrete piled nearly a metre high - had splintered a wooden post as thick as a man's waist - had once even crumpled and buckled a plate of niconium steel.  Now that fist struck lethally at Thr'un's temple, just above the ear where the skull is thinnest, and crushed it."

It was a very vivid fight scene that stuck with me for along time.