# Mystery book series with an alien bird side-kick and a Protagonist called something like Jarrod

Tags: story-identification

So I have several email addresses over the last 20 years based on the main character from a 3-4 part book series. I'd love to remember the title and re-read them so I can explain the meaning of my email address - it has become my persona.

I read the series in around 1996-97. It was set in space and centred around a lone-ranger type character called Darek Jarrod (I think spelled correctly). He had a telepathic owl-like alien sidekick who flew with him in his little fighter starship thing.

There was some sinister, somewhat ethereal council of overlords who needed to be defeated - I think there was a lead antagonist as well. Eventually, 4 books later, he manages to defeat them.

It's not much to go on - I think it was aimed at young adults/adolescents as I was a teen at the time.

Any help for this 20 year+ mystery would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jarrod ( :S )

Comment: pretty sure it's darek.  you got a link on a Derek Jarrod tho?

Answer (score 9):

This sounds a bit like the [Last Legionary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary) series by Douglas Hill which was in another answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30561/scifi-series-from-the-80s-or-70s-main-character-with-bionic-powers/30589#30589).

Parts that match:

I read the series in around 1996-97.

> Written in the late 70s early 80s

It was set in space and centred around a lone-ranger type character called Darek Jarrod (I think spelled correctly).

> The books tell of the adventures of Keill Randor, the last survivor of his planet's population, who are annihilated at the beginning of the book Galactic Warlord.

He had a telepathic owl-like alien sidekick who flew with him in his little fighter starship thing.

> They also reveal how they captured Keill so easily – a telepathic avian life form from another galaxy known only as 'Glr'.

There was some sinister, somewhat ethereal council of overlords who needed to be defeated - I think there was a lead antagonist as well.

> The Overseers' leader, Talis, explain to Keill that his home planet was destroyed by a malevolent entity known as 'The Warlord'

Eventually, 4 books later, he manages to defeat them.

> Yep. 5 books total.

Comment: hmm I think that's the one! amazing.  the only problem is... where the heck did I get Darek (spelled correctly i think) Jarrod from.  
I'm gonna get those books tho cus I think you got part of the mystery!